column not allowed here oracle
Although I double quoted strings I still get column not allowed here error. Help please. Thanks in advance.
This is my table:
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
  DATE_ID           DATE                        NOT NULL,
  DATE_NAME         VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  DATE_DATE         DATE,
  DAY_ID            NUMBER(1),
  YEAR_ID           NUMBER(4),
  QUARTER_ID        NUMBER(1),
  MONTH_ID          NUMBER(2),
  YEAR_MONTH_ID     NUMBER(6),
  WEEK_ID           NUMBER(2),
  YEAR_WEEK_ID      NUMBER(6),
  WEEKEND_FLAG      NUMBER(1),
  ETL_LOAD_TIME     TIMESTAMP(6),
  ETL_UPDATE_TIME   TIMESTAMP(6),
  SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID  NUMBER(5)
)

This is my procedure's parameters
    v_week NUMBER;
    v_day DATE;

cur_d is my cursor which is
 for cur_d in 1..7

This is my statement:
    v_query :='insert into mytable(date_id,date_name,date_date,day_id,year_id,quarter_id,month_id,year_month_id,week_id,year_week_id,weekend_flag,etl_load_time,etl_update_time,source_system_id) values 
    (v_day,to_char(v_day,''yy/mm/dd''),v_day,cur_d,to_number(to_char(v_day,''yyyy'')), to_number(to_char(v_day, ''Q'')) ,
    to_number(to_char(v_day, ''MM'')),to_number(to_char(v_day, ''YYYYMM'')) ,v_week,
    to_number(to_char(v_day,''iyyyiw'')),
    case when to_char(v_day,''DY'') in (''SAT'',''SUN'') then  1 else 0 end,sysdate ,sysdate ,10)';


It looks like you're building a dynamic statement, then executing that - which you haven't shown? If so (a) v_day is out of scope within the dynamic execution and should be passed in with using, but more importantly (b) why are you do this dynamically at all when it seems that could be a static SQL insert statement? (You may not even need the loop or any PL/SQL; and most of the columns in your table could be virtual...)

I havent posted the whole procedure. I am trying to create a dimension table which is from monday to monday ,52 weeks each year. I am trying to do it for 10-15 years to fill the table. I posted the whole procedure code now

You seem to be building a dynamic insert statement as v_query, and then - presumably - run it with execute immediate, something like:
v_query = ' ... ';
execute immediate v_query;

When you do that the references to the local PL/SQL variables v_day, cur_day and v_week in your dynamic statement are out of scope - those variables do not exist as far as the execution is concerned, so they are seen as potential column names, causing the error.
If you really wanted to do this then you could use bind variables and pass the values in:
v_query :='insert into mytable(date_id,date_name,date_date,day_id,year_id,quarter_id,month_id,year_month_id,week_id,year_week_id,weekend_flag,etl_load_time,etl_update_time,source_system_id)
values (
  :v_day,
  to_char(:v_day,''yy/mm/dd''),
  :v_day,
  :cur_d,
  to_number(to_char(:v_day,''yyyy'')),
  to_number(to_char(:v_day, ''Q'')),
  to_number(to_char(:v_day, ''MM'')),
  to_number(to_char(:v_day, ''YYYYMM'')),
  :v_week,
  to_number(to_char(:v_day,''iyyyiw'')),
  case when to_char(:v_day,''DY'') in (''SAT'',''SUN'') then  1 else 0 end,
  sysdate,
  sysdate,
  10
)';

execute immediate v_query using v_day, cur_day, v_week;

except you'd need to repeat the values for each bind position:
execute immediate v_query using v_day, v_day, v_day, cur_day, v_day, v_day, v_day, v_week, v_day, v_day;

You can also use the alternative quoting mechanism to avoid having to escape all the quotes within the statement.
But it doesn't need to be dynamic, just use static SQL:
insert into mytable(date_id,date_name,date_date,day_id,year_id,quarter_id,month_id,year_month_id,week_id,year_week_id,weekend_flag,etl_load_time,etl_update_time,source_system_id)
values (
  v_day,
  to_char(v_day,'yy/mm/dd'),
  v_day,
  cur_d,
  to_number(to_char(v_day,'yyyy')),
  to_number(to_char(v_day, 'Q')),
  to_number(to_char(v_day, 'MM')),
  to_number(to_char(v_day, 'YYYYMM')),
  v_week,
  to_number(to_char(v_day,'iyyyiw')),
  case when to_char(v_day,'DY') in ('SAT','SUN') then  1 else 0 end,
  sysdate,
  sysdate,
  10
);

You can also avoid most of that by changing the table to have virtual columns, as @MT0 showed, and you would then have a much simpler (and still static) insert statement.
You can also use a hierarchical query to avoid the PL/SQL loop if you want, which might mean you don't need to use PL/SQL at all.

I'm still getting column not allowed error using
execute immediate v_query using v_day, cur_day, v_week; or execute immediate v_query using v_day, v_day, v_day, cur_day, v_day, v_day, v_day, v_week, v_day, v_day;

With static SQL, I can do it. But I also want to beautify my code :)

@charmander Dynamic SQL is not good practice. If you do not have to use it then don't as code that is "beautiful" but more difficult to maintain is not as useful as code that is easy to maintain.

@charmander - did you change v_query to use bind variables? (If you insist on using dynamic SQL - I don't know why you would want to for anything that can be done statically... it's harder to code, read and maintain, and only gives run-time errors not compile-time errors.)

my bad, i changed it then executed EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  v_query using v_day, v_day, v_day, cur_d, v_day, v_day, v_day, v_day,v_week, v_day, v_day; it worked.

@MT0 , you are right. :) I will do it statistically, it is more meaningful. Maintenance is more  important

If you want to derived values from another column then use virtual columns.
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
  DATE_ID           DATE NOT NULL,
  DATE_NAME         VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)
                    GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TO_CHAR(date_id, 'YY/MM/DD')),
  DATE_DATE         DATE
                    GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CAST(date_id AS DATE)),
  DAY_ID            NUMBER(1)
                    GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TRUNC(date_id) - TRUNC(date_id, 'IW') + 1),
  YEAR_ID           NUMBER(4)
                    GENERATED ALWAYS AS (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_id)),
  QUARTER_ID        NUMBER(1)
                    GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(date_id, 'Q'))),
  MONTH_ID          NUMBER(2)
                    GENERATED ALWAYS AS (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_id)),
  YEAR_MONTH_ID     NUMBER(6)
                    GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(date_id, 'YYYYMM'))),
  WEEK_ID           NUMBER(2)
                    GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(date_id, 'IW'))),
  YEAR_WEEK_ID      NUMBER(6)
                    GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(date_id, 'IYYYIW'))),
  WEEKEND_FLAG      NUMBER(1)
                    GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CASE WHEN date_id - TRUNC(date_id, 'IW') >= 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
  ETL_LOAD_TIME     TIMESTAMP(6),
  ETL_UPDATE_TIME   TIMESTAMP(6),
  SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID  NUMBER(5)
);

This has the added benefit that if you change date_id then all the other columns will be synchronized and the changes will be propagated.
Then if you want to populate it with several years of data you can use a hierarchical query:
INSERT INTO mytable(date_id, etl_load_time, etl_update_time, source_system_id)
SELECT DATE '2024-01-01' + LEVEL - 1,
       SYSTIMESTAMP,
       SYSTIMESTAMP,
       1
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY
       DATE '2024-01-01' + LEVEL - 1 < DATE '2026-01-01';


If you want a procedure then use:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FILL_CAL_DATE(
  v_start_day IN DATE,
  v_num_weeks IN NUMBER DEFAULT 572
)
IS 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO mytable( date_id, etl_load_time, etl_update_time, source_system_id)
  SELECT TRUNC(v_start_day, 'IW') + LEVEL - 1,
         SYSDATE,
         SYSDATE,
         10
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= v_num_weeks * 7;
END FILL_CAL_DATE;
/

Which is much simpler than your current procedure and only requires a single INSERT statement (rather than generating one-per-day) so will be faster as it generates fewer log entries.
You can call it using:
BEGIN
  FILL_CAL_DATE(DATE '2024-01-01');
  COMMIT;
END;
/


If you do want non-virtual columns (I would advise against it) then your procedure could be:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FILL_CAL_DATE(
  v_start_day IN DATE,
  v_num_weeks IN NUMBER DEFAULT 572
)
IS 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO mytable(
    date_id,
    date_name,
    date_date,
    day_id,
    year_id,
    quarter_id,
    month_id,
    year_month_id,
    week_id,
    year_week_id,
    weekend_flag,
    etl_load_time,
    etl_update_time,
    source_system_id
  )
  WITH dates (date_id) AS (
    SELECT TRUNC(v_start_day, 'IW') + LEVEL - 1
    FROM   DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= v_num_weeks * 7
  )
  SELECT date_id,
         TO_CHAR(date_id, 'YY/MM/DD'),
         date_id,
         TRUNC(date_id) - TRUNC(date_id, 'IW') + 1,
         EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_id),
         TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(date_id, 'Q')),
         EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_id),
         TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(date_id, 'YYYYMM')),
         TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(date_id, 'IW')),
         TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(date_id, 'IYYYIW')),
         CASE WHEN date_id - TRUNC(date_id, 'IW') >= 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
         SYSDATE,
         SYSDATE,
         10
  FROM   dates;
END FILL_CAL_DATE;
/

fiddle
